# Format text/cells in whole row based on date in column A

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a sheet where each row starts with the dates of each Sunday throughout the year. I want to change the formatting for all rows that are "past". I also want only the NEXT Sunday (based on the current date) to be formatted separately.

How might this be achieved?

Comment: This site is for asking about specific code issues and you haven't given any examples of what you've tried it what issues you are having. Please add more information so that we can help you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please try : Format - Conditional formatting..., Custom formula is and:

```
=and($A1<today(),$A1<>"")
```

with one formatting of your choice and:

```
=and($A1<today()+7,$A1<>"")
```

with another. In both cases the Range: should be as wide as suits (say A:Z). <kbd>Save rules</kbd>.

Comment: It worked great! Thank you!   Is there a way to format the text to "Bold"?